# How can I use a weighted MSE as loss function in a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am trying to use a custom loss function for calculating a weighted MSE in a regression taks (values in the task:-1,-0.5, 0, 0.5 , 1, 1.5, 3 etc.). Here is my implementation of custom loss function:

```
import tensorflow
import tensorflow.keras.backend as kb

def weighted_mse(y, yhat):
    ind_losses = tensorflow.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, yhat)
    weights_ind = kb.map_fn(lambda yi: weight_dict[kb.get_value(yi)], y, dtype='float32')
    # average loss over weighted sum of the batch
    return tensorflow.math.divide(tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(tensorflow.math.multiply(ind_losses, weights_ind)), len(y))
```

I am running an example which is working:

```
weight_dict = {-1.0: 70.78125, 0.0: 1.7224334600760458, 0.5: 4.58502024291498, 1.0: 7.524916943521595, 1.5: 32.357142857142854, 2.0: 50.33333333333333, 2.5: 566.25, 3.0: 566.25}
y_true = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor([[0.5],[3]])
y_pred = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor([[0.5],[0]])

weighted_mse(y_true, y_pred)
```

But when inputted into my model, it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'
```

Here is how I use the custom loss function:

```
    model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss={
        "predicted_class": weighted_mse
    })
```

**EDIT:**

when changing `weight_dict[kb.get_value(yi)]` to `weight_dict[float(yi)]` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is it guaranteed that your model only outputs like -1.0, 0, 0.5, 1.0, etc? (which is strange for a regression model!), and 2) Am I right into thinking that what you want to achieve is `weight_y_true * mse(y_true, y_pred)` where `weight_y_true` depends on the value of `y_true`?

Comment: 1)  yes it is guaranteed 2) exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically the idea of sample weight. When using training API of Keras, alongside your data you can pass another array containing the weight for each sample which is used to determine the contribution of each sample in the loss function.

To use it, you can use `sample_weight` argument of `fit` method:

```
model.fit(X, y, sample_weight=X_weight, ...)
```

Note that `X_weight` should be an array of the same length as `X` (i.e. one weight value for each training sample). Further, if `X` is a `tf.data.Dataset` instance or a generator, this argument does not work and instead you need to pass the sample weight as the third element of the tuple returned by `X`.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens in an old version of tensorflow. There are 2 things you can try:

1. Add this line to the jupyter notebook when you are importing tensorflow like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

2. Upgrade tensorflow with the following command in prompt:

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

> This is most probably because of eager execution. See the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/enable_eager_execution) for more info.